# Space of smooth section of a vector bundle as Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, smooth-manifolds, sobolev-spaces, vector-bundles

Currently, I am studying the space of sections $\Gamma(E)$ of a vector bundle $(E,M,\pi)$. If $h$ is a riemannian bundle metric over $E$, and $\mu$ is a volume form in $M$, we can define the following inner-product in $\Gamma(E)$:
$$\langle s,s'\rangle=\int_Mh(s,s')\, \mu.$$
This inner product turns $\Gamma(E)$ into a pre-Hilbert space that is not complete: there exists Cauchy sequences that do not converge.

From my (very limited) knowledge of Hilbert spaces, we can consider the *complection* of $\Gamma(E)$ respect to the distance function determined by $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. If so, we obtain a Hilbert space that contains $\Gamma(E)$ as a dense subset.

However, in most Differential Geometry books I always find that $\Gamma(E)$ is completed respect to another inner-product, producing a new Hilbert space called *Sobolev space*.

I don't understand why the autors always consider the *Sobolev complection* instead of the (more natural) complection that we have presented.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you complete with respect to the distance induced by this inner-product, you get the space of $L^2$ sections of the vector bundle $E$. But $L^2$ is a special (but important) case of a Sobolev space ($L^2=H^0$). People use more general sobolev spaces because those are the natural spaces to consider PDEs (you can talk about weak-regularity objects, you can talk about derivatives in a suitable generalized sense, these spaces are complete so analysis is possible, you have the wonderful Sobolev embedding theorems; in particular you can go from generalized solutions to classical solutions etc).